# Processing by myxxxxxController#index as */*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this random call hitting my app that shows up in the logs as :

```
Processing by myxxxxxController#index as */*
```

What is */* any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means format of request, for example text/javascript. And */* means any format